# ShinyApp Error During Deployment: Execution Halted

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am having trouble during deployment to shinyapps.io of an application that is working locally. The application uses **shiny** and **shinydashboard**. I am able to run the app in RStudio, but when I click publish it halts execution with no discernible error reported. The error message I receive is:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 71390052 error: Unhandled Exception: 
Execution halted
```

Also, when I run `shinyapps::showLogs()` nothing is returned.

I have checked to see that all required packages are updated and to the best of my knowledge they are. A call to `sessionInfo()` gives:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gtable_0.1.2         gridExtra_2.0.0      ggplot2_1.0.1        dplyr_0.4.2         
[5] jsonlite_0.9.16      DT_0.1.32            shinydashboard_0.5.0 shiny_0.12.2
```

I know this isn't a lot to go on, but since the application works fine locally and there are no error messages, I'm not sure what code would be useful. I've looked at any other SO questions I could find on shiny deployment errors, but they all have a useful error message.

Any debugging suggestions, help, or other ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you're not using the latest version of R, that could be something to work on. Also, have you logged in shinyapps.io? Does the project exist there, and if so, is it "ok"? I had issues with renaming a project once, solved by deleting the instance online (via browser) and uploading again.

Comment: I can try updating to the latest version of R, but I have one other app deployed at shinyapps.io on my account. After I attempt to publish/deploy from RStudio the app has a status of undeployed, rather than 'running' or 'sleeping', etc. when I log in to my account in shinyapps.io

Answer (score 0):

After some toying around and re-configuring the server and ui codes into separate server.R and ui.R files I have found a solution. It seems subtle to me, but I think the error may be because I originally built the app in a single file calling `shinyUI` and `shinyServer` functions explicitly, which I know are no longer necessary in newer versions of shiny. The basic app skeleton was:

```
ui <- shinyUI( "some code here")
server <- shinyServer( function(input, output, session) { "some other code here"})

shinyAPP(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Upon splitting this into two separate files as stated above I was still having publishing errors. However, when I removed the explicit calls to `shinyUI` and `shinyServer` the app deployed fine.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue in the future.